# How to use parent CSS from Shadow DOM

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom, web-content, webcontent

I have css from parent application that I want to use inside a web-component made by shadow dom. I don't want to copy css from parent aplication to web-component, but right now, the web-component can't see the parent application css, how can I do that?

```
parent app:

<style>
.pretty-button {
  color: green
}

</style>
<body>
  <button class="pretty-button">Got It</button>
  <custom-element></custom-element>
</body>

web-component made by shadow dom: 

<!--doesn't work because the shadow dom can't use parent css class-->
<body>
  <button class="pretty-button">Got it from shadow dom</button>
</body>
```

Comment: do you really need to use shadow dom? if you want to reuse css from parent application, you can create web component without shadow dow (or else you must copy, or import, css style)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadow DOM is protected from outside CSS. This is *by design*.

TL;DR:

If you want the outside CSS to affect DOM inside the shadowRoot of a custom element then you need to either:

1. Use a `<slot>` or
2. Copy the CSS into the shadowDOM

Here are three answers I have given on similar questions:

- [I have an element that i have declared as a shadow dom but the style is affecting the other elelemts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487961/i-have-an-element-that-i-have-declared-as-a-shadow-dom-but-the-style-is-affectin/49495982#49495982)
- [Why does my Web Component CSS not show? I am not using shadowDOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937760/why-does-my-web-component-css-not-show-i-am-not-using-shadowdom/48937761#48937761)
- [slot selector limit in webcomponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268817/slot-selector-limit-in-webcomponent/49280503#49280503)