# I have an element that i have declared as a shadow dom but the style is affecting the other elelemts

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

The code is

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/document-register- 
element/1.7.2/document-register-element.js"></script>
<div id = "1">
<style>
div {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: brown;
}
</style>
 </div>

 <script>
  document.getElementById('1').attachShadow({mode: "open"})
</script>
<div id = "2"></div>
<div id = "3"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the jsfiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/o5r229hf/

I have declared div id 1 as a shadow dom but div id 2 and 3 are getting the style. Could there be something with the order that i am have written the elements?

Comment: You're using the `div` selector. This will apply the styling to all div elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the `<style>` tag as a child to the `<div id="1">` and not as a child of the shadow DOM. So the `<style>` exists outside the the shadow that you created.

The CSS must exist inside the shadowRoot to affect elements within that shadowRoot.

Any CSS outside a shadowRoot is not supposed to affect the elements inside the shadowRoot. [One minor exception is when using slots.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268817/slot-selector-limit-in-webcomponent/49280503#49280503)

If your code is limited to what you are showing above then you need to move the CSS into the shadowRoot by doing something like this:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('1');

var s = el.attachShadow({mode: "open"});

while(el.firstElementChild) {
  s.append(el.firstElementChild);
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #F00;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "1">
  <style>
  div {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: brown;
  }
  </style>
  <div>I1</div>
</div>
<div id="2">
  <div>I2</div>
</div>
<div id="3">
  <div>I3</div>
</div>
```

What this does is copies the children of `<div id="1">` into the shadowRoot that you created.

This moves the `<style>` tag inside which makes it only affect that `<div>` and no others.

If your code is not limited to something like you have above then just create the CSS as a child of the shadowRoot.

**UPDATE:**

Even if your code isn't in shadow DOM you might need to add your CSS into your container's shadow DOM. [Here is how to handle that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937760/why-does-my-web-component-css-not-show-i-am-not-using-shadowdom)

Answer (score 0):

Using shadow DOM, you can target the parent element in the CSS with `:host`:

```
<div id="1">
<style>
:host {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: brown;
}
</style>
</div>
```

However, shadow DOM is not properly handled yet, even by the most recent browsers.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:host

Comment: This only applies to the `:host` of the shadowRoot where the CSS lives. If you don't put the CSS in your shadowRoot then these will apply to the shadowRoot that is being used, possibly the shadowRoot for `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

**1st solution: template literals**

Define the `<style>` element directly in the shadow dom:

```js
document.getElementById('1').attachShadow({mode: "open"}).innerHTML = `<style>
:host {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: brown;
}
</style>
<slot></slot>`
```

```html
<div id="1">D1</div>
<div id="2">D2</div>
<div id="3">D3</div>
```

**2nd solution: html template**

Define all the content of you shadow dom in a `<template>` tag and then insert it in the shadow dom.

```js
var tpl = document.querySelector('template')
document.getElementById('1').attachShadow({mode: "open"}).appendChild(tpl.content)
```

```html
<template>
  <style>
    :host {
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      background-color: brown;
    }
  </style>
  D1
</template>

<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2">D2</div>
<div id="3">D3</div>
```